# Proteger Código de Plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Como Ofuscar ou Encriptar o código de um plugin que foi desenvolvido para wordpress?

Eu tenho um plugin que só funciona confirmando o e-mail de compra na tela de ativação. E se eu deletar o usuário da minha base de dados (que puxa os e-mails de quem comprou) o plugin para de funcionar no cliente.

A questão é. O código está aberto e alguém pode simplesmente remover as minhas funções de proteção, por esse motivo quero encriptar, para evitar a pirataria do meu plugin.

Não é o caso de um plugin open source, eu tenho alguns no wordpress org, mas esse não será aberto.

Comment: Olha, se for um JS que vc desenvolveu, veja esse site: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

Comment: O Plugin é 90% php!

Comment: Mas então não tem com o que se preocupar. O PHP vai rodar no servidor, o cliente só vai ver o resultado, não a estrutura do que tu desenvolveu.

Comment: É um plugin wordpress, basta ele ir até wp-content/plugins/meuplugin que ele vai ver o código todo.

Comment: Nesse caso é só tu colocar um .htacess dentro da pasta de plugins com a opção Options -Indexes que não vai listar nada. Agora, se o código é .php, não vai adiantar nada, pq nem abrir ou baixar ele vai conseguir.

Comment: Não posso inserir um arquivo htaccess na pasta de plugins de quem comprar o meu plugin. Eu tenho que fazer isso dentro do meu plugin, sem influenciar em nada no wordpress de terceiros que vierem a comprar.

Comment: Existem vários plugins pagos por ai, tenta ver como eles fizeram